# Compare dates from two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is there any optimum way to achieve this solution?

Email column from df1 needs to run through email column of df2 and if a match is found then needs to check that df1.CreationDate is between df2.StartDate and df2.StartDate+3months.
Both dataframes contain ~200000 records.

```
df1:

   BillNum         Email                 CreationDate
0    101       def@gmail.com              24-Mar-2022
1    102       xyz@test.com               10-May-2019
2    103       hjk@test.com               20-Mar-2022

df2:


   RefNum      Email                     StartDate                
0    13        abc@test.com             01-Mar-2022              
1    12        def@gmail.com            15-Mar-2022              
2    11        xyz@test.com             12-Feb-2022 

   
Output df:

   BillNum       Email        CreationDate  RefNum     StartDate
0   101      def@gmail.com     24-Mar-2022    12      15-Mar-2022
```

Comment: Is this not just a simple merge on the email key?

Comment: The quick / direct answer to your question is, yes.  Now, what have *you* tried / researched already? (We expect a solid measure of effort to be put in from your side.)

Comment: Is `10-May-2019` a typo?

Comment: @S3DEV 

df1['result'] = df1.Email.isin(df2.Email)
df_output= df1[df1['result'] == True]

i am not sure how to handle the date condition

Comment: @richardec nope..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do a merge and then filter:

```
df1['CreationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['CreationDate'])
df2['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['StartDate'])
tmp = df1.merge(df2)
tmp = tmp[(tmp.CreationDate > tmp.StartDate) & (tmp.CreationDate < tmp.StartDate + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3))]
```

Output:

```
>>> tmp
   BillNum          Email CreationDate  RefNum  StartDate
0      101  def@gmail.com   2022-03-24      12 2022-03-15
```

Answer (score 1):

After merge you can use timedelta with days as argument to filter dates.

```
import datetime
df3=df1.merge(df2)
df3[(df3['CreationDate']>=df3['StartDate']) & (df3['CreationDate']-df3['StartDate']<datetime.timedelta(90))]
```